# 3D Vertices To 2D Image Conversion

Tags: 3d, mapping, 2d, perspective, vertices

All I would like to do is create a viewport which maps a 3D terrain of flat squares to a 2D perspective.

Imagine looking out across a field which was perfectly flat. The further away blocks of terrain would appear slanted inwards further towards the horizon, and would also look shorter.

I have done a TON of research on how to scientifically do this correctly and came across this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_angle

(except this article is in 2D. I would want it to also account for the "height" or z dimention of the viewport)

Is there a simpler way to do this and create true perception rather than having to program:

-3D ray/sphere intersection

-distance from point to point on a sphere

Pretty much what I'm asking is if there exists a simpler way to map vertices in a 3D world to a 2D plane while staying true to perspective warping?

Any helpful articles or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to use [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) and a [perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Perspective_projection) matrix.  This doesn't require any distance computations at all:  per vertex, it requires a 4x4 matrix multiplication and a division to scale the final 2D point.

And, yes, it is scientifically and geometrically correct, although I should note that it assumes a flat, camera-like projection screen and an ideal, pinhole-like lens.  If you want a "visual angle"-based [fisheye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens) view the best option may be to add [barrel distortion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_distortion) as a post-process....

You should probably start with an introductory computer graphics text, like *3D Computer Graphics* by Alan Watt.  An older, "classic" work is *Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice* by Foley, van Dam, et al.